# How to create single array for same key but different values

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, json, arraylist

How to create single array for same key but different values in nodeJs with unique productId
but having different productImage with same productId i want productImage should be an array 
and with same productId, productImages are in this productImage array.

```
var data = [
   {
      "productID":18,
      "productTitle":"Watch",
      "productImage":"1588148225540.jpg"
   },
   {
      "productID":18,
      "productTitle":"Watch",
      "productImage":"15881482433232.jpg"
   },
   {
      "productID":19,
      "productTitle":"Shirt",
      "productImage":"1588148214343.jpg"
   }
]
```

My expected output should be:

```
[
   {
      "productID":18,
      "productTitle":"Watch",
      "productImage":[
         "1588148225540.jpg",
         "15881482433232.jpg"
      ]
   },
   {
      "productID":19,
      "productTitle":"Shirt",
      "productImage":[
         "1588148214343.jpg"
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `uniqBy` function from `lodash` library

```
const result = _.uniqBy(products, 'productID');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer

```
var data = [
   {
      "productID":18,
      "productTitle":"Watch",
      "productImage":"1588148225540.jpg"
   },
   {
      "productID":18,
      "productTitle":"Watch",
      "productImage":"15881482433232.jpg"
   },
   {
      "productID":19,
      "productTitle":"Shirt",
      "productImage":"1588148214343.jpg"
   }
]

let output =[];
          data.forEach(function(item) {
            var existing = output.filter(function(v, i) {
              return v.productID == item.productID;
            });
            if (existing.length) {
              var existingIndex = output.indexOf(existing[0]);
output[existingIndex].productImage =
output[existingIndex].productImage.concat(item.productImage);
            } else {
              if (typeof item.productImage == 'string')
                item.productImage = item.productImage;
                item.productThumbImage = [item.productThumbImage];
                output.push(item);
            }
});
```